# Calling setRequestedOrientation without actually rotating the screen in Android

Tags: android, rotation, surfaceview

I am struggling with a quite rare problem.
Here it goes:

I have a SurfaceView and there is a JNI-side thread that handling the rendering operations on it (Let say Render-thread). For "some" reason I need to rotate my drawings by myself inside the render-thread. To achieve this, the render thread queries the rotation status from the android framework. And I can see the rotated screen whenever the device is rotated, but there is a problem: if I rotate the device, the screen rendered by Render-Thread is rotated, but Android UIs (such as notification bar, toast message, etc) are not rotated (Of course!). To resolve this problem, I use setRequestedOrientation function to tell the Android to rotate my Activity. Then I can also see the properly rotated Android UIs. At this moment, my real problem happens: The race between Render-Thread and Android's screen rotation stuff (I guess surface flinger?).

Apparently, if I call setRequestedOrientation function, Android framework rotates the screen by itself, while my Render-thread is also drawing the rotated screen. And this results in a glitch.

My question here is that:

Is there a way to tell Android framework not to rotate the SurfaceView while I'm still calling setRequestedOrientation?

Comment: When you physically rotate the device, and the framework wants to rotate the screen contents, it grabs a screen shot, and puts that up in front of the application (which you can no longer see). It then restarts the current Activity. When the Activity finishes and is ready to draw in the new orientation, the framework animates rotating the screen shot, and then drops the screen shot, leaving you looking at the newly-rotated Activity. I'm not sure what exactly you're doing or seeing, but it's easy to come up with ways to interact badly with this.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid such kind of rotation stuff by the framework. Because my app handles the rotation by itself. And it is kind of a conflict.

Comment: You can lock the orientation for your app by adding e.g. `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your AndroidManifest.xml.